# The type or namespace 'dotliquid' cannot be found, but I have added the reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

So I have vs.net 2010.

I downloaded the DotLiquid.dll from: https://github.com/formosatek/dotliquid

I created a simple method to test it:

```
public static void DL()
{
  var template = Template.Parse("hi {{name}}"); // Parses and compiles the template

  Console.WriteLine("Template is : " + template.Render());
}
```

I have:

```
using DotLiquid;
```

at the top of the file.

No idea why I am getting this error, very confused!

Comment: Have you added reference to the Dll?

Comment: Yes, and it also have Save local copy set to true.

Comment: Open up the `csproj` file in notepad and check the `hintpath` property on the reference. It might be pointing to different path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also check that you have the version that is tergetted to the same .Net framework version as what you are using.

This means if you are using the framework v4.0 Client Profile, you may have to retarget to the full version. If you are already using the fll version and DotLiquid is using the Client Profile, that is fine.

If you are targetting v4, and DotLiquid is using 3.5, you will have to retarget your project to 3.5, or recompile DotLiquid to v4.

Did that make sense?

Comment: I couldn't answer my own question, but yes that is what I did.  client profile was the killer!

Comment: Looks like you've solved this problem, but just FYI: DotLiquid on .NET 4.0 is now compatible with the Client Profile; it no longer requires the full version of .NET 4.0. (That change is up on github, but hasn't been released yet - it will be released shortly.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the reference (dll) to your project? Right click the References folder in your solution explorer and add it that way.

Comment: There has to be something else your missing or not doing.  I downloaded the .dll and referenced it and worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my checklist of things to do:

1. Create a new blank C# project, add a reference to this assembly.
2. Please make sure that no issues are seen under References, like shown in the example here:

[image]

3. Build the application. Make sure no errors are seen.
4. Add a using statement and the method as you've posted in your original message.
5. Build again, see if buuild is OK or not.

I could easily build the code you posted with no errors.